# missing FROM-clause entry for table when trying to update / insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

Try to update a table with a new set of values,

if the values already exist then it should update the fields, if it doesn't then it should insert the fields.

```
WITH f AS (
SELECT 1 as MarketId,  
                            'dros@test.com' as userName, 
                            28 as age, 
                            1 as isPremiumMember, 
                            1 as isSubscribed, 
                            '2021-03-12T17:07:30' as LastModifiedOn
    from members
    ) 


    
    INSERT INTO members
(age,isPremiumMember,isSubscribed, lastModifiedOn) 
    VALUES (f.age,f.isPremiumMember,f.isSubscribed,f.lastModifiedOn)
    ON CONFLICT (age,isPremiumMember,isSubscribed,lastModifiedOn)
DO UPDATE SET age= EXCLUDED.age,isPremiumMember = EXCLUDED.isPremiumMember,isSubscribed= EXCLUDED.isSubscribed,lastModifiedOn= EXCLUDED.lastModifiedOn;
```

however when I run the query I get this error:

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "f"
```

trying to write this in plain SQL

INSERT INTO members
(age,isPremiumMember,isSubscribed, lastModifiedOn)
select age,isPremiumMember,isSubscribed,lastModifiedOn from f
ON CONFLICT (age,isPremiumMember,isSubscribed,lastModifiedOn)
DO UPDATE SET age= EXCLUDED.age,isPremiumMember = EXCLUDED.isPremiumMember,isSubscribed= EXCLUDED.isSubscribed,lastModifiedOn= EXCLUDED.lastModifiedOn;

tried adding the unique constraint as select as recommend below. this is my current statement.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359440/postgresql-insert-on-conflict-update-upsert-use-all-excluded-values

Answer (score 1):

Try using select instead of f.

```
INSERT INTO members
(age,isPremiumMember,isSubscribed, lastModifiedOn) 
    select age,isPremiumMember,isSubscribed,lastModifiedOn from f
    ON CONFLICT (age,isPremiumMember,isSubscribed,lastModifiedOn)
DO UPDATE SET age= EXCLUDED.age,isPremiumMember = EXCLUDED.isPremiumMember,isSubscribed= EXCLUDED.isSubscribed,lastModifiedOn= EXCLUDED.lastModifiedOn;
```

Comment: tried this but have this: error there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022362/no-unique-or-exclusion-constraint-matching-the-on-conflict

Comment: You need to place a unique key if you want to use the conflict function

Comment: so the solution is to create a new table? is there not another way?

Comment: No no, you can use this `ALTER TABLE members ADD UNIQUE (age,isPremiumMember,isSubscribed,lastModifiedOn);`

Comment: I've altered the columns but still getting the there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification.  pasting my current statement for clarity

Comment: Can you add that as primary key as the sample?

Answer (score 0):

Simplified example for an *upsert* query (avoiding the CTE):

---

```
\i tmp.sql

create table members (
        member_id integer primary key
        , name text
        , eyes text
        , hair text
        );

INSERT INTO members(member_id, name, eyes, hair) VALUES
 (1, 'Lisa', 'brown', 'brown'),
 (2, 'Bob', 'brown', 'brown');

\echo Initial
SELECT * FROM members order by 1;

INSERT INTO members(member_id,name, eyes, hair)
VALUES(1, 'Alice', 'blue', 'blonde' )
ON conflict (member_id) DO
UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name, eyes = EXCLUDED.eyes, hair = EXCLUDED.hair
        ;

\echo After the update
SELECT * FROM members order by 1;
```

---

Results:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2
Initial
 member_id | name | eyes  | hair  
-----------+------+-------+-------
         1 | Lisa | brown | brown
         2 | Bob  | brown | brown
(2 rows)

INSERT 0 1
After the update
 member_id | name  | eyes  |  hair  
-----------+-------+-------+--------
         1 | Alice | blue  | blonde
         2 | Bob   | brown | brown
(2 rows)
```