# Insterting key-value pair to public postgreSQL table from node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, psql

I don't know much of a pSQL, however the behaviour that i want is to:

> insert a key (string type) - value(string type) into a public table (named stats)

Code i am using is like this

```
let value = await db.query({
                text: "INSERT INTO public.stats (key,value) values ($1,$2) ON CONFLICT (key) DO UPDATE SET value = $2;",
                values: [wantedStamp,inDb] 
            });
            const rep: Reply_ip_get_background_image_timestamp = {
                name: wantedStamp,
                date: inDb
            };
            res.json(rep).status(200);
```

Where wantedStamp is a string variable declared before, inDb is the string form of date. When i try to use this i get the error:

```
error: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
...some modeule errors amd than...
length: 148,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P10',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'plancat.c',
  line: '842',
  routine: 'infer_arbiter_indexes'
```

EDIT------
Now my code is like

```
let value = await db.query({
                text: "INSERT INTO stats (key,value) VALUES($1,$2) ON CONFLICT (key) WHERE ((key)::text = $1::text) DO UPDATE SET value = $2;",
                values: [wantedStamp,inDb] 
            });
            const rep: Reply_ip_get_background_image_timestamp = {
                name: wantedStamp,
                date: inDb
            };
```

but it still doesn't work ...

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+there+is+no+unique+or+exclusion+constraint+matching+the+ON+CONFLICT)

Comment: does the key have a unique constraint? if not, add one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022362/no-unique-or-exclusion-constraint-matching-the-on-conflict)

Comment: @YashKumarVerma it did not sadly ...

Comment: @YashKumarVerma how can i add unique constraint

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194438/can-i-add-a-unique-constraint-to-a-postgresql-table-after-its-already-created